# Howto contact a forum user directly?

Tags: discussion

I'm new at the Ask Ubuntu Forum and want to ask a specific user (Rinzwind) about one of his answers ([What is the "Wanna Cry" ransomware's possible impact on Linux users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914623/what-is-the-wanna-cry-ransomwares-possible-impact-on-linux-users), here about the initial phishing mails). Is there another, faster way then collect enough points to comment the question, e.g. a personal message?

Comment: *whistles innocently*

Comment: Obligatory note: Ask Ubuntu is *not* a forum

Comment: ...ok, and the mobile search is unusable. Sorry for the duplicate question. BTW: could I earn rep points at other Stack Exchange Platforms?

Comment: The search is just... not very good. Using an external search engine usually works better :) no need to apologise at all. If you earn 20 rep on any site you'll be able to access chat (I *think* that means chat everywhere) and if you earn 200 rep on any site you'll get an association bonus of 100 points on all sites where you have an account (and every time you start a new one) which will give you the basic privileges like commenting anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another, faster way then collect enough points to comment the question, e.g. a personal message?

You need a mere 20 rep to join askubuntu chat where you can find this absolutely amazing user called Rinzwind you would like an audience with.

So answer something and get 2 upvotes. Takes seconds to get if the answer is good ;)

Comment: Wow - THAT was fast and helpfull! My question especially for Rinzwind: could you provide a sample of a Wannacry-Phishing-E-Mail? In the meantime I will collect reputation points ;)

Comment: @user689443 Just going to say as a security professional that there's *multiple* types of phishing messages that could contain it - a single sample is useless, you need a large set of samples to really get the gist of it.  Common sense "Does this email look right" practices apply.

Comment: Not exactly. Until now I couldnt find ANY sample of a wannacry phishing E-Mail at the internet...so one E-Mail would be enough for me to confirm an additional infection vector.

Comment: @user689443 in Ubuntu Chat there are several people that can supply you with an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. That means that you can comment your own question and any answer to your own question, even if your reputation is less than 50 points.

> The following community members will be automatically notified of your comment:
>
> - the owner of the post you're commenting on
> - one additional user when your comment contains a @username

Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment

If you want to comment anywhere else you need 50 points reputation!